# 2 different products with same rfid tag

Tags: collision, rfid

I'm doing a smart shopping cart as a college project, the problem is if I have 2 pieces of the same product (2 same tags) in the cart, how can I make sure the reader reads both of them?

Comment: How do you determine if your reader reads all products in the cart regardless of whether they are the same product or not?

Comment: Tag ID's are generally unique; just because the product is the same doesn't mean that the tag is going to be identical. An inventory control system would already have a database entry with the rfid uid as a primary key, and a foreign key out to the productid. As to whether the RFID antenna can read both tags -- many (most?) readers are capable of talking to (performing an inventory on) multiple transponders simultaneously, so you should see all tags when you ask the reader for all tags in field range.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are working with `UHF ISO 18000-6C` tags, you should take a look at the bank memory organization.

Those are compose with four block:

1. User bank
2. TID bank
3. EPC bank
4. Reserved bank

Right now, you only must be worried about the tag identification (TID) structure. Check the `TID bank` of your tags and focus to read those bytes.

Regards